# How did Xavier control wire/rope to remove helmet of Sebastian Shaw in First Class?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In "X-Men: First Class", Xavier paused Sebastian Shaw after removing his telepathy-immune helmet. But, he did it using a wire or rope.
Telepathic power is supposed to control minds of living organisms, not wire/rope type objects. So, how did he do it?
[image: Wire or rope behind helmet of Sebastian Shaw]
[image: Removed helmet by wire or rope]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Magneto removed the helmet, not Charles. Once the helmet was removed, Charles then paused Shaw.

It was discussed in the X-Jet previously that Magneto's mission was to find the black out area that Charles couldn't access and to remove it. When Magneto found out it was Shaw's helmet, magneto them removed the helmet when Shaw was distracted.

Comment: Have you really watched "X-Men: First Class" movie? BTW, I've attached the scenes from movie in question... Take a look at them..

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean, Magneto didn't remove the helmet. You can see this in snapshots (from movie) attached in my question. Please, see the photo I attached in question: Magneto is locked & helmet is removed from opposite side using a wire/rope.

Comment: Magneto is the master of magnetism. He doesn't need his hands to use his powers. The wires were made of metal and were easily pliable to Magneto.

Comment: Why did someone downvote? My explanation is exactly how the movie went...

Comment: You should watch the movie again... Just before helmet removal, Magneto was in emotional state without any concentration... At the time of helmet removal, Magneto said, "No Charles!!!".. And, the next scene flick displayed "Concentrating Xavier"..

Comment: No, it was Magneto manipulating the wire, not Xavier.  I just finished watching the movie.  OghmaOsiris is correct.  Xavier cannot move things.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: He says, "Now, Charles!"  Turn on closed captioning/subtitles.  It's very clear.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the movie script.. Just watched that scene again & listened "NOW, Charles!".. :) Its clear too (without subtitles). Perhaps, last time my biasing towards great power of Xavier forced me to listen that..

Answer (score 6):

I believe, though it has been a long time since I saw the movie, that it was Magneto, not Xavier, as Oghma said.

If we're both mistaken, however, it's worth pointing out that Xavier ALSO has telekinetic abilities, though they're nowhere near as strong as his telepathic skills.

Comment: do you have any references to show he has telekinetic abilities?

Comment: Sure.  Here's the [Marvel Database](http://marvel.wikia.com/Charles_Xavier_%28Earth-616%29) article on him.  Check under 'Powers & Abilities'.

Comment: Do you have any in-movie references?

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Xavier in the X-Men movies has zero telekinetic powers.