# Why can't Xavier move his legs with his mind?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I always wondered why it is possible for Charles Xavier to move objects with his mind, but not his own legs?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: He's telepathic, not telekinetic.
That means he can "take control" of minds, not objects.

Comment: He can't move things with his mind.

Comment: Don’t worry though, it’s a [relatively common mistake](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8201/how-did-xavier-control-wire-rope-to-remove-helmet-of-sebastian-shaw-in-first-cla).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I have to tell you, I had literally never come across anyone make that mistake until I joined Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JamesSheridan well it would make sense that you would see it here... it's a forum for asking questions about topics you might not know much about.

Comment: i didnt even ask this...i just let my PC turned on...-_-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Introduction

This answer build on the version of Charles Xavier that does have low-level telekinesis, as can be read [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/Charles_Xavier_(Earth-1610)).

### Why he physically can't

I will not go into his exact disability, but merely state that he has no motor function in his legs and cannot move them in the same way an able-bodied human would.

### With his telekinesis

Given that he can telekinetically lift the weight of his legs, I would guess that he potentially could, but to what good?

As he, per his disability, has no motor function in his legs (that is, can't move them the traditional way), he would have to grab a telekinetic hold of his legs and move them forward with his mind.

It would, it seems to me, be similar to (though not the same as) a normal, disabled person using his arms to move his legs (i.e. using a force other than the muscles of his legs and the signals from his brain to them). The legs would move, and take him forward (given that he could telekinetically keep the muscles flexed so as not to fall), but it would waste a lot of unnecessary energy.

Comment: If Xavier could use his telekenisis to move his legs and control the muscles, how would that be any different from the way a person normally controls his/her legs?  Because a person already uses the mind to send electrical impulses to control the motor functions of his/her legs.  Xavier doing this telekeneticaly returns that basic motor function sans the electrical impulses.  With enough practice, he would be able to do it as simply as a non disabled person does.  He'd essentially be reteaching himself how to walk, thereby, not using any energy at all.

Comment: @Robert I suppose that would be possible, if he can indeed control the muscles that thoroughly. Like you said, it would be different in that it wouldn't be electric impulses from his brain telling his muscles to move, but rather his telekinetic powers moving the legs. I'd say that it wouldn't be the muscles doing the work, but the telekinesis.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren You're right, it would be the telekenisis working the legs.  But if he got proficient enough at it, he could very well train his brain into thinking that it's a 'normal' operation of the brain.  A type of muscle memory.

Comment: @Robert The body of any animal is designed to be able to move its parts. Most of it is done subconsciously. We don't have to learn to move our legs. Moreover, the movement of a leg, a foot or a hand is way more complex than moving an object or even several. A leg is built up of a multitude of muscles, nerves and bones. Xavier would most likely be able to learn to walk by telekineses, but it would still be an acquired ability. And would he be able to move naturally, or would he look like Edgar in Men in Black? And would he be able to direct his telekineses elsewhere while sustaining his walk?

Comment: @SixthOfFour, Animals most certainly do have to learn how to walk, if they didn't, they'd be born walking.  Have you never seen a baby or another animal learn how to walk?  We may be designed to do things like that, but we still have to learn how our parts move to make the process work, making it an acquired ability.  Again, if he were to have enough practice at it he would be able to do it 'naturally' and build a type of muscle memory, allowing him to use his abilities elsewhere.

Comment: @Robert While your point is correct, the point of my comment was that we do not have to learn to move our legs, not even the finer movements, we have to learn only how to correlate the movements. Xavier would have to learn not only how to correlate the movements, but also how to actually create each movement. While he probably would be able to walk, my questions stand: Would he be able to make it look natural, and, considering that TK is not his major ability, would he be able to direct is elsewhere while sustaining his walk, or would he have to sit down to be able to move another object?

Comment: @SixthOfFour, as I said, with enough practice, he would because it would become a type of muscle memory.  Of course, it would take years to develop this, but once it became second nature to him, he would eventually learn to multi-task in the same manner normal people can watch tv/talk on the phone at the same time and retain the information they gathered from both.  Or listen to music while working out.  It's training the brain to do multiple things at once and when it comes to a character like Xavier it wouldn't be too difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Marvel Wiki, [Xavier does indeed have telekinetic abilities](http://marvel.wikia.com/Charles_Xavier_(Earth-1610)), or at least the version that lived on Earth-1610...

> **Telekinesis**: Xavier is capable of a low-level form of telekinesis, it is unknown how much weight Xavier is capable of lifting with his telekinesis. It is known however that he is capable of lifting himself and his wheelchair up a flight of stairs, shunting Magneto into Earth's atmosphere and exploding the ball of metal which Magneto was (presumably) contained within, and levitating a Sentinel.

Perhaps 'low-level telekinesis' does not extend to moving his legs, although he can lift a Sentinel apparently.